# Is there a way to access each element's attribute in generator in nested for loop?

Tags: python, list, dictionary, generator, nested-loops

I want to run a nested loop over a generator and a list. Within the loop, I want to access each element's attribute.

I found similar code questions about looping over an object's attributes, but I wasn't able to solve the problem I'm having.

Below is my code work:

```
gen = api.search_submissions() # gen is generator of submissions

f_list = ['id','title']

sub_dict = {
    'id':[],
    'title':[]
}

for sub in gen:
    for name in f_list:
        sub_dict[name].append(sub.name)
```

I ran into a problem that python does not assign values to 'name' inside .append method.

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 3, in <module>
AttributeError: 'submission' object has no attribute 'name'
```

How can I get around with this problem? Thank you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> I ran into a problem that python does not loop over 'name' inside .append method.

The loop *is* looping over the values of `f_list` and assigning them to the variable `name`. The problem is that attribute access expressions, such as `sub.name`, do not check the local scope for a matching variable and replace the name with its value. The presence or absence of a local variable named `name` does not change the fact that `sub.name` will look for an attribute literally named "name" on the sub object.

You can use `getattr` to get an attribute of an object, given a string holding the attribute name.

```
sub_dict[name].append(getattr(sub,name))
```

Comment: Yeah, I made a confusing statement. Thanks, I checked it and it works like a charm. :)